# It is possible to add numbers from 0-99 at the end of all line?

Tags: notepad++, emeditor

Hello i got something in format:

```
Marcin:Marcin
Pawel:Pawel
```

i want to add numbers between 0-99 at the end of line so result should be like:

```
Marcin:Marcin1
Marcin:Marcin2
..
Marcin:Marcin99
Pawel:Pawel1
Pawel:Pawel45
..
Pawel:Pawel99

etc.
```

Does there exist any command or plugin what can do it?

I tried manually but its so waste time, also i tried find it on google but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example insert_num.py):

```py
import re

def insert_num(match):
    strout = ''
    maxcount = 100
    for counter in range(1, maxcount):
        strout += match.group() + str(counter)
        if counter < maxcount - 1:
            strout += "\n"
    return strout
    
editor.rereplace(r'^.+(?<!\d)$', insert_num)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> insert_num)
- Done

**Result for given example:** (shortened)

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! This is what i wanted u are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **JavaScript** macro for **EmEditor** to add numbers from 1-99 at the end of all lines.

```
Redraw = false;
nLines = document.GetLines();
arr = new Array();
for( i = 0; i < nLines; ++i ) {
    arr[i] = document.GetLine( i + 1 );
}
document.selection.SelectAll();
document.selection.Delete();
for( i = 0; i < nLines; ++i ) {
    if( arr[i].length != 0 ) {
        document.Numbering( arr[i] + "1","1",99,0);
    }
}
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Macro.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Macro.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while the document you want to edit is active.

Comment: its another way to do it? i got like 1k lines and i would like to add them all numbers between 0-99

Comment: Make a zero-width vertical selection (drag and drop while pressing ALT) on the right side of text, then you can select Numbering (Alt+N).

Comment: Alternatively, you can select `Marcin:Marcin`, press Ctrl+Shift+A, press End, and select Numbering (Alt+N).

Comment: I was misunderstanding your question. Here is a macro you want to run for EmEditor. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use EmEditor's  \J mode.

Find：**^.+$**

Replace: **\J var str=""; for( i=1; i<100; i++) {str+="\0"+i+"\n"; str.replace(/\n$/g,"");}**

**var str=""**  -> Define an empty string

**for( i=1; i<100; i++)**  ->The number of cycles can be changed from 100 to other numbers

**str+="\0"+i+"\n"** ->Add numbers **i** and line breaks at the end of the found line **\0**, and add values to str via **str+**, connecting them all together

**str.replace(/\n$/g,"")** ->Clear an extra line break

[Screenshot from another link](http://ys-d.ysepan.com/198138917/713746221/keeriii883I4K5H2LP4f0/Snipaste_2023-06-07_06-04-38.jpg)